# Issues in installing bluez-utils and running the command bluetoothctl

Tags: bluetooth

I am struggling to pair a device with my raspberry pi via bluetooth. I am referring to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth) tutorial. As per that, there are 2 packages needed for this.
Bluez and Bluez-utils. I have installed both of them. When I run the command bluetoothctl it says command not found.

This is what the guide says.
Install the bluez and bluez-utils packages. The bluez package provides the Bluetooth protocol stack, and the bluez-utils package provides the bluetoothctl utility.
Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Which version of bluez did you install? bluetoothctl is only available in bluez 5.